# Import JAR that uses .so files into a new android project

Tags: android, jar

I'm trying to build an app using a library packed in a JAR file.

When I call one of the functions I get this error:

Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing **thelibrary.class**

I've check the source code of the library and I think it crushes when loading some .so files ( System.loadLibrary("usb-1.0"); 
those files do exists in the JAR project under libs/armeabi (libusb-1.0.so)

I guess the .so files are not packed with the JAR, so how do I get them to be found in my project ?

(tried to copy them to libs/armeabi but the same exception is thrown....)

I do not get any link / build errors....

Thanks.

Comment: Is "the JAR project" your own, or one from a third party? If "the JAR project" can be repackaged as an Android library project, NDK binaries work, as I've done that before: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-anddown

Comment: It is not my own, but I can view the sources for that project. should I recompile it ?

Comment: Not so much "recompile" as repackage it as an Android library project. Then reference that Android library project from your app, instead of using the JAR.

Comment: Do you really have an android-compatible build of libusb?  Which actually works, without root?  More immediatley, the build tools do not really support .so's in JARs, so a key question would be if the .so is actually making it into the APK and onto the device.

Comment: when I use the vendor example it works on device.... not rooted.

Comment: @CommonsWare -That solved the problem, you might post it as answer, and I should accept. but the real problem is that my app is going to be a library as well, and I don't know if I can make it a library while it is using other libraries....

Comment: @CommonsWare Hi I developed an application that contains .so file.Now I want to make it .so file.Idea is that I do not share my code to devlopers.I share my .jar file and then they develop.Like we are using android.support.v4.jar file for using fragmentation.How can make jar file my apps.Let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ordinary JAR file will not work for distributing something that is dependent upon an Android NDK-compiled library. However, an Android library project *can* also distribute an NDK-compiled library.

> but the real problem is that my app is going to be a library as well, and I don't know if I can make it a library while it is using other libraries

Assuming that "make it a library" == "make it an Android library project", this is fine, so long as projects attempting to use your library project also have access to the other library project.